# Creating Multiple Bar Charts With C# and dundas

Tags: c#, asp.net, dundas

Hi guys I am having trouble adding bar charts on my code. What I need to do is from the pie chart is to make a bar chart for every piece that it has. Unfortunately I am having a hard time doing so. The Main objective that I am trying to do is to create a separate detailed bar graph based on the GroupName. This Is my C# Code:

```
    void StartReport10()
    {
        Chart c = Chart11;

        string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLRC_debug"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_SLRC_GetReport_MajorAndMinorCauseCategories", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60; //(1 minute)

        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rtype", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Timeline10.RangeTypeIndex;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@y1", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Timeline10.FYFrom);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r1", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Timeline10.RangeFrom);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@y2", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Timeline10.FYTo);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@r2", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Timeline10.RangeTo);

        int top = Int32.Parse(tbTop1.Text);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@top", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = top;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MROProjFilter", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = MROProjReport3.GetSelectedMROProjFilter;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TradeIntercoFilter", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TradeInterco3.GetSelectedIntercoTradeFilter;

        if (CustomerFilter2.IsEnabled && CustomerFilter2.IsValid)
        {
            string a = CustomerFilter2.GetStrSelection;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@str", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = a;
        }
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        ds.Tables["Table"].TableName = "Table_for_Major";
        ds.Tables["Table1"].TableName = "Table_for_Detailed";

        c.DataSource = ds.Tables["Table_for_Major"];
        c.Series.Clear();
        c.Series.Add("Default");
        c.Series[0].ValueMemberX = "GroupName : %";
        c.Series[0].ValueMembersY = "% of Total LineCount";
        c.Series[0].Type = SeriesChartType.Pie;
        c.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Inside";
        c.Series[0]["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
        c.Series[0].ShowInLegend = false;
        c.DataBind();

        //Chart Title
        c.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Dundas;
        c.Titles.Clear();
        c.Titles.Add("PDSL Major & Minor Cause Categories");
        c.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
        c.Titles.Add(Timeline10.FYRangeFrom + " - " + Timeline10.FYRangeTo);
        c.Titles[1].Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);

        c.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        c.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.XAngle = 5;
```

Comment: What part isn't working

Comment: To inquisitiveldiot the code itself is working it's the creation of bar charts is the one that I am having trouble with. I have been looking everywhere for a code to make bar charts even on the dundas website but nothing works as of the moment

Answer (score 0):

I found this list of necessary steps to create a barchart:

> The basic steps are:
>
> 1. Initialize the Chart control. Define any non-default properties.
> 2. Initialize the ChartArea. Define any non-default properties. Each
>      ChartArea has an Axis collection (X,Y and X2,Y2), so be sure to set
>      these properties if necessary.
> 3. Initialize the Series(s) to be displayed in the chart. Without a Series, there are no DataPoints to be displayed, so be sure to
>      create at least one.
> 4. Optionally, create a Legend.
> 5. Add DataPoints to the Series.
> 6. Add the ChartArea, Series, and Legend elements to the Chart.
> 7. Add the Chart Control to an element of the page.

And heres a [link](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1180) to the full page with an example (Dundas).

You can either create separate Chart(-objects) or try adding a new ChartArea to your existing Chart and set `Series["barchart"].ChartArea = "ChartArea2"` to allow different Chart-types in the same Chart-object.